# Visual Studio - Can't remove binary reference from website project

Tags: visual-studio, nhibernate, dll, reference

I'm planning to test an upgrade from NHibernate 2 to 3. First port of call seems to be to remove the reference to NHibernate.dll from the website project.

If I simply delete the file from the bin folder, it reappears when I build the website. So the website knows it's supposed to be there. If I open the properties for the website and look at the list of references, NHibernate.dll is not there. In fact, none of my binary references are there, only the project and .NET references.

That's me stuck. Anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that you have other libraries referencing NHibernate (e.g. BusinessLogic or DAL)? If so, you need to change the reference there.

If that is not the case, try replacing it in the bin folder directly. Don't forget to replace the other DLLs as well (Iesi.Collections.dll for 3.1 and Iesi.Collections.dll, Remotion.Data.Linq.dll, Antlr3.Runtime.dll for 3.0, and the DLLs for the proxies (lazy loading).

By the way, something that proved to be helpful in such situations is having a designated folder for all external DLLs that do not belong to the .NET Framework and referencing the DLLs from there. In doing so, when updating you only need to replace the DLL in that folder and it will automatically be used.

Comment: The problem was indeed that the dll was referenced indirectly rather than directly.